# Mac OS shutting down upon booting to the login screen

Tags: macos

I don't know why but when ever I start up my MacBook Pro it keeps shutting down upon it reaching the login screen it also does this for the recovery.  NOTE the machine was enrolled to MDM but was removed by contacting the company

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. So if you boot to internet recovery (or some other recovery), the machine won’t run for 10 minutes straight? Is that a correct interpretation of what you have on your hands?

Comment: Restart in Safe Mode and see if you can get past the login screen. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262. I'd also recommend performing an SMC reset: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: @BaconDuctTape I’d +1 that answer - it’s not really a comment seeking clarification, but a proposed solution / troubleshooting step